# Identify the caller (or how pass parameter) of a callback (JSON) function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, jsonp

When i request

> BASE_URL + 'json/valueone?callback=fnCallBack0'

the response from server is treated in a callback function. This function receives (ASYNCHRONOUS) data (JSON format) but do not include the initial parameter "valueone"

```
var BASE_URL = ...
function fnCallBack(data){
    if (data != null) {
    // HERE...I NEED ID <====================
    // arguments.callee.caller <==================== dont work
        console.log('information', data);
    }
}

// onclick callback function.
function OnClick(info, tab) {
    var arrH = ['valueone', 'valuetwo'];
    arrH.forEach(function(value) {
        var scrCallBack = document.createElement('script');
        scrCallBack.src = BASE_URL + 'json/' + value + '?callback=fnCallBack';
        //BASE_URL + 'json/one?callback=fnCallBack0';
        document.body.appendChild(scrCallBack);
    });
```

My solution is to create an intermediate function correlative name (fnCallBack0, fnCallBack1, ...), a global array, and a counter. Works fine, but this is not OOP, is a fudge.

```
var BASE_URL = ...
//global array
var arrH = [];

var fnCallBack0 = function(data){
    fnCallBack(data, '0');
}
var fnCallBack1 = function(data){
    fnCallBack(data, '1');
}

function fnCallBack(data, id){
    if (data != null) {
        console.log('information', data + arrH[id]);
    }
}

// onclick callback function.
function OnClick(info, tab) {
    var i = 0;
    arrH = ['valueone', 'valuetwo'];
    arrH.forEach(function(value) {
        var scrCallBack = document.createElement('script');
        scrCallBack.src = BASE_URL + 'json/' + value + '?callback=fnCallBack' + (i++).toString();
        //BASE_URL + 'json/one?callback=fnCallBack0';
        document.body.appendChild(scrCallBack);
    });
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: '%s',
    contexts: ["selection"],
    onclick: function(info) {console.log(info.selectionText)}
});

var idConsole = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: 'console',
    contexts: ["selection"],
    onclick: OnClick
});
```

I tried with inject function as code in html page, but i receeived "inline security error", and a lot of similar questions.

Please, NO AJAX and no jQuery.

This is my first post and my first chrome extension
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how anything of this has to do with OOP, but a solution would be to just create the callback function dynamically so that you can use a closure to pass the correct data:

```
function fnCallBack(data, value){
    if (data != null) {
        console.log('information', data + value);
    }
}

// onclick callback function.
function OnClick(info, tab) {
    ['valueone', 'valuetwo'].forEach(function(value, index) {
        // unique function name
        var functionName = 'fnCallback' + index + Date.now(); 

        window[functionName] = function(data) {
            fnCallBack(data, value);
            delete window[functionName]; // clean up
        };

        var scrCallBack = document.createElement('script');
        scrCallBack.src = BASE_URL + 'json/' + value + '?callback=' + functionName;
        document.body.appendChild(scrCallBack);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thx for yout reply
ERROR : Uncaught ReferenceError: fnCallBackfnCallback01395614491126 is not defined callback=fnCallBackfnCallback01395614491126
(anonymous function)
Maybe "window[functionName] = function(data) {fnCallBack(data, value);"

Comment: Seems like you did `'?callback=fnCallBack' + functionName` instead of `'?callback=' + functionName`.

Comment: really sorry ... i try again

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next it. This way you mark your question as solved.